# Как открыть один и тот же проект в двух окнах в Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Мне требуется открыть в двух окнах 2 git-ветки одного и того же проекта. Надеюсь это возможно?

Comment: Если только физически на диске задублировать. При смене ветки git меняет файлы на диске

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть git log (меню Git/Show git log)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нужной ветке выбрать правой кнопкой мыши Show repository at revision
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откроется дерево файлов нужной ревизии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываете нужный файл. Он откроется в отдельной вкладке с указанием id коммита
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]